# wpf prism 6 refresh view after culture change

Tags: wpf, view, prism-6

Shell has 2 regions : menu and main

- `MenuModule` has `MenuView` that fills menu region
- `WelcomModule` has `WelcomeView` that fills main region
- `WelcomeView` uses `DynamicResource` for label content

`MenuModule` handles culture change :

- change culture
- change resourcedictionary
- publish event `LanguageChangedEvent`

`WelcomeModule` subscribe `LanguageChangedEvent`

How can I refresh View so that `DynamicResource` reload based on changed dictionary ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DynamicResource` is refreshed automatically.

Instead of changing resourcedictionary inside MenuModule I reload it inside WelcomeModule

Here is the new steps

`MenuModule` handles culture change :

- Change culture
- publish event `LanguageChangedEvent`

`WelcomeModule` handle dictionary change :

- Reload dictionary based on new culture

Comment: "Reload dictionary based on new culture" -> How do you do that?